# Remove all children from scrollable frame in CustomTkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

**The issue I'm facing:** Remove widgets from previous searchButton press and only display widgets from current searchButton press.

```
  tempList = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=570, height=250)
    tempList.place(x=0, y=35)

def searchProcess():
    requestedComic = searchBar.get("0.0", "end")
    searchComicURL = comicBase + requestedComic + "&ig=&eg=&status="
    searchComicURL = searchComicURL.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
    print(searchComicURL)
    searchComicRequest = Request(searchComicURL,
                                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    searchComicHTML = urlopen(searchComicRequest).read()
    comicTitles = scrapeTitles(searchComicHTML)

    if len(tempList.winfo_children()) == 0:
        for x in range(len(comicTitles)):
            comicButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(tempList, width=300, height=30, text=comicTitles[x])
            comicButton.pack()
    else:
        tempList.destroy()
        comicList = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=570, height=250)
        comicList.place(x=0, y=35) 
        for x in range(len(comicTitles)):
            comicButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(comicList, width=300, height=30, text=comicTitles[x])
            comicButton.pack()


searchButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, width=70, height=30, fg_color="#581845", text="Search", command=searchProcess)
searchButton.place(x=515, y=0)
```

**My Goal:**
Remove all widgets in scrollableFrame and display the new widgets.

**What I tried doing:**

1. I made a scrollableFrame that is called tempList that would be added when the program is opened, when tempList has more than 0 elements, it will be deleted and replaced with a new scrollableFrame called comicList. Once searchButton is pressed again after the removal of tempList, comicList will be removed and replaced with a new scrollableFrame that has only the new widgets without the presence of the old ones. (The code shown above)
2. Before the new widgets are added, I tried getting the children of comicList and used the destroy() function on them, but the widgets remained unaffected and kept showing still. The code:

````
comicList = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(root, width=570, height=250)
comicList.place(x=0, y=35)

def searchProcess():
    requestedComic = searchBar.get("0.0", "end")
    searchComicURL = comicBase + requestedComic + "&ig=&eg=&status="
    searchComicURL = searchComicURL.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
    print(searchComicURL)
    searchComicRequest = Request(searchComicURL,
                                 headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    searchComicHTML = urlopen(searchComicRequest).read()
    comicTitles = scrapeTitles(searchComicHTML)

    for child in comicList.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()

    for x in range(len(comicTitles)):
            comicButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(comicList, width=300, height=30, text=comicTitles[x])
            comicButton.pack()```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example